# CSS: Position Element between rows of floating unordered list elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to modify some CSS layout and I stuck. I have an unordered list of elements which span 100% of the width and are floated to the left:

[image]

Now each of these list elements contains a (on default hidden) container with more details to this element. These details should be visible (only one at a time) if you click on the element. And now there is my problem. These details should be displayed below the row in which the clicked element is located and all other elements should be pushed down. Like so:

[image]

Now I'm stuck. I got it working by using `position:absolute` on the details element and assigning a `margin-bottom` using JavaScript on all the elements in the same row. This works, but I would prefer a solution where the clicked element does not need to modify all the other elements, just itself.

Is this possible? Using JavaScript is possible, IE9+ should be supported.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0jfkmpk/) of my current solution.

**Why I don't want to do it that way?**

Unfortunately this should be responsive and therefor I don't want to manipulate all elements in a row (as the rows can change anytime).

Thanks! I hope it's clear what I try to do?

Comment: There is sadly no way to accomplish this in CSS. You are going to have to row count in Javascript (if they're always changing you could keep adding the elements innerWidth to a variable and see when it hits bigger than the window width. The loop iteration you are in (usually i) - 1 is then amount of columns). Then use `$(element).detach().inserAfter(i)`, if that makes sense.

Comment: ... and of course if screen width changes *after* the full-width component has been added (like, the tablet/phone is rotated), then everything would have to be re-computed.